# Variable availability after script loading

Tags: javascript, eslint

I currently have two files that ESLint is giving me errors in:

```html
<body>
<!-- .. -->

<script src="./script1.js"></script>
<script src="./script2.js"></script>
</body>
```

```js
// script1.js

function $() { // error: '$' is defined but never used
    // some helper functions
}
```

```js
// script2.js

var component = (function ($) {
    // ..
})($); // error: '$' is not defined
```

If script tags are loaded in the order they appear in the document, then why `$` isn't available in script2.js? Isn't `$` known at compile time, and that's why I should be able to use it in the IIFE?

Answer (score 1):

> If script tags are loaded in the order they appear in the document, then why `$` isn't available in script2.js?

It is, provided the function declaration you've shown is at global scope.

> Isn't `$` known at compile time, and that's why I should be able to use it in the IIFE?

Yes, you should and can:

```html
<script>
function $() { // No error here
    // some helper functions
}
</script>

<script>

var component = (function ($) {
    console.log(typeof $); // "function"
})($); // No error here

</script>
```

The issue is that ESLint works at the file level unless you're using modules so it can understand what's where. There are comments you can use to tell it that (for `script1.js`) the `$` is used by other code, and (for `script2.js`) that `$` is a global it can assume is present. But really what I'd suggest is get started using modules rather than relying on globals.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is really useful to the OP, though... May ditch it.

Comment: I see. Just recently I added es-lint to my project. Is it possible that the error message has something to do with it not being able to find `$`?

Comment: @mjfneto eslint probably can't see it. That's not really a javascript error, but a linting one. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals

Comment: I'm going to find a way to fix it them in ES-Lint docs. Thanks a lot. Should I ditch the question?

Comment: @mjfneto - ESLint works at the file level unless you're using modules so it can understand what's there. There are comments you can use to tell it that (for `script1.js`) the `$` is used by other code, and (for `script2.js`) that `$` is a global. But really what I'd suggest is get started using modules rather than relying on globals.

Comment: @mjfneto - I'm not sure. Let's see if there's a good dupetarget now that we know you're using ESLint...

Comment: I've been advised before of problems related to polluting the global scope. The whole objective of this personal project is to get used with variations of the module pattern. I'll try to disable this es-lint rule then. Thank you for editing the answer!

Comment: @mjfneto - No worries! I'd say let's leave the question and answer, may be useful to others in the future. I'll fold my comment about ESLint into the answer in case comments get cleaned up (as they periodically do).